# Restrict my Amazon S3 bucket access to specific Country

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How I can restrict my Amazon S3 bucket to other country I don't want access to my bucket from the specific country how to do that? what to use Cloud front or Amazon S3 policy.

Comment: You are aware of the fact that by using proxies/VPNs anybody from anywhere can claim to be requesting from basically any country?!

Answer (score 3):

Amazon S3 does not offer geographic restrictions.

However, **Amazon CloudFront** *does* allow [Restricting the geographic distribution of your content - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html).

So, you could:

- Create an **Amazon CloudFront distribution** with the Amazon S3 bucket as an 'origin'
- [Restrict access to Amazon S3 content by using an origin access identity (OAI) - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)
- Create a **Bucket Policy** that grants access to the bucket to the OAI:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EH1HDMB1FH2TC"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Configure a **geo-restriction** on the Amazon CloudFront distribution

Users will only be able to access the S3 bucket via the CloudFront distribution, and that access will be restricted based upon the geographic configurations you set on the CloudFront distribution.